# Determining which button was clicked in a form and getting its 'unique value' in a PHP script

Tags: php, forms, http-post

It's easy to tell which button was clicked from a set of buttons if each of the button has a unique name, and the name is known at the time of backend processing (when retrieving the data sent from the form, in a php script). Even easier if the set contains not more than 2-3 buttons. But what to do when button names are unique, but not known, and set contains more  than 20 buttons. To explain further, I am using an example:

Consider Facebook's add friend module. The site checks current user's (account owner's) city/school or other related data, performs a database query, retrieves a random list of users from same city/school. The template presents the list where each raw has a blue button saying  'Add Friend' at its right corner and user info at its left. No one other than the current user knows which button is going to be clicked. Now assume one funny thing, that non of the fb engineers know what AJAX or JS is. In this case, how to retrieve the unique ID of the user whose ADD FRIEND button was clicked and process database queries in order to send him/her a friend request and insert/update rows accordingly. I couldn't find a way to retrieve the unique value (that could have been assigned as the value of button's 'name' attribute) of the clicked button to process ahead.

Comment: It could be as simple as attributes on the button - `<button data-userid="12345">` then the AJAX query includes the `userid` value in the call to the external PHP page?

Comment: A hidden form field seems the most likely culprit. Could also be a data attribute on the button itself.

Comment: @Jay-How to access that data attribute in PHP?

Comment: @user5648637 You dont access it in php you would use javascript to grab the value and then send that to php `$('#button1').data('userid')` But as said above hidden form is the best bet without AJAX

Comment: @JammyDodger231 Is there no way to get things done without touching JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential option is to have multiple hidden forms that have all the different 'Add Friend' buttons for example:

```
<form method="post" action="addFriend.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="123" />
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Friend" />
</form>
```

If you have multiple forms like this and just changed the value of the "userid" input you could click on each form and it would go to a page to add that user.

If you are wanting to do this without a page refresh or relocation then I believe the only way you can do it is through AJAX

Comment: Sounds good!! I think that is the solution I was looking for. THANKS :)

Comment: No problem :) as I said in the question you can have many of those forms with different userids and the effect will be the same

Comment: Definitely, but a little engineering, like removing additional <form> elements and wrapping everything inside a single <form> and giving same name but different values to each hidden form may cause the script to generate errors. BUT THAT IS THE PROBLEM WITH ALL FORMS, SO ITS OKAY.